# Using 'for' or 'to'

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-objects

The collaborative nature of the program offers customized solutions for customers and channel partners.

or

The collaborative nature of the program offers customized solutions to customers and channel partners.

Which one of the above is grammatically correct?

Comment: Both prepositions are correct, their usage depends on the meaning you want to convey. Compare: prepositions with offer: ***to*** - *She offered drinks to her guests.* - 
 ***for*** -  *They have offered over £500,000 for the house.* http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=offer —- In your sentence I’d use “to” customers.

Comment: @Hachi I'd agree that both are correct, but it is not because "offer" can take "for". In the example you've provided the meaning of "for" is "as an exchange". It can hardly be interpreted that way in the sentence given by Anand.

Comment: @JulesCocovin - as you can read in my comment, I suggest the preposition “to” as far as Anad sentence is concerned.

Comment: @Hachi Yes, of course. And I wholeheartedly agree with your viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct but the meaning changes depending on how you interpret the relations between the words. I would dissect the sentences as follows:

**The program offers something. The something are solutions for customers and partners.** 
(solutions for customers and partners = one entity)

OR

**The program offers solutions. The offer goes out to customers and partners.**
("to" is related to "offer")

So, basically, the meaning is similar, but not identical. If you use "solutions for", the focus is on the fact that the solutions are dedicated to those businesses. As a result they should be happy to buy them, possibly (?). If you use "offer solutions to", you merely say that the solutions can be used by the businesses but maybe not (?).

See here for the collocations for "offer": http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=offer

Comment: So I believe "for" is similar to "which"- used in restrictive clauses and "to" with "that" used in non-restrictive clauses.

Comment: The collaborative nature of the program offers customized solutions for customers and channel partners = The collaborative nature of the program offers customized solutions which/that are dedicated to customers and channel partners.

The collaborative nature of the program offers customized solutions to customers and channel partners = The collaborative nature of the program offers customized solutions, which can be used by customers and channel partners.

Comment: But the point is what we attach the preposition to. Is it: "offer solutions meant for WHOM?" Or is it: "to WHOM offer the solutions"? I'd be easier if I could draw one of Chomsky's "trees" :)